# Trouble using genericra to integrate activemq and glassfish when using failover protocol

Tags: glassfish, jms, activemq-classic, high-availability, generic-jms-ra

I'm attempting to use activemq in glassfish using the genericra resource adapter provided with glassfish 2.1. I have found a few pages with helpful information including http://activemq.apache.org/sjsas-with-genericjmsra.html.

I have actually had success and been able to get MDBs to use activemq as their JMS provider, but I'm running into an issue as I'm trying to do some more complicated configuration. I want to set up a master-slave configuration, which would require my clients to use a brokerURL of failover:(tcp://broker1:61616,tcp://broker2:61616). In order to do this, I set the following property when calling asadmin `create-resource-adapter-config` (I have to escape '=' and ':'):

```
ConnectionFactoryProperties=brokerURL\=failover\:(tcp\://127.0.0.1\:61616,tcp\://127.0.0.1\:61617)
```

However, I am now getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when my application starts up. I suspect the comma in between the two URLs is the culprit, since this works fine:

```
brokerURL\=failover\:(tcp\://127.0.0.1\:61616)
```

Just wondering if anyone has dealt with this issue before. Also wondering if there is a better way to integrate with glassfish than using the generic resource adapter.

EDIT: I forgot to escape the colon after the second tcp, but unfortunately that didn't fix the issue I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up switching to use the resource adapter provided by activemq that comes in the lib/optional directory.

In case anyone is interested, here are the steps I followed to get it working

```
asadmin create-resource-adapter-config --property ServerUrl=failover\:(tcp\://localhost\:61616,tcp\://localhost\:61617) activemqra

asadmin deploy --name activemqra <path to activemq-rar-5.4.2.rar>
```

Then to create resources:

```
asadmin create-connector-connection-pool --raname --connectiondefinition javax.jms.ConnectionFactory --transactionsupport XATransaction jms/MyQueueFactoryPool

asadmin create-connector-resource --poolname jms/MyQueueFactoryPool jms/MyQueueQFactory

asadmin create-admin-object --raname activemqra --restype javax.jms.Queue --property PhysicalName=MyQueue jms/MyQueue
```

To get an mdb hooked up, I had to add this in the sun-ejb-jar.xml

```
<mdb-resource-adapter>
                <resource-adapter-mid>activemqra</resource-adapter-mid>
                <activation-config>
                    <activation-config-property>
                        <activation-config-property-name>DestinationType
                        </activation-config-property-name>
                        <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue
                        </activation-config-property-value>
                    </activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property>
                        <activation-config-property-name>destination
                        </activation-config-property-name>
                        <activation-config-property-value>MyQueue
                        </activation-config-property-value>
                    </activation-config-property>
                </activation-config>
            </mdb-resource-adapter>
```

To hook this up to a spring JMSTemplate:

```
<bean id="ConFac" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>jms/MyQueueQQFactory</value>
        </property>
        <property name="resourceRef">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="myqueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>jms/MyQueue</value>
        </property>
        <property name="resourceRef">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mdbTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="conFac" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="myqueue" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: This helped me as I am replacing OpenMQ with ActiveMQ in Glassfish 3. All of our configuration is done through Ant and the asadmin steps you outlined helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known defect in genericjmsra, see: http://java.net/jira/browse/GENERICJMSRA-50

In the comments a fix in ObjectBuilder.java is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're not escaping the colon in the second uri.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the missing escape, but unfortunately that wasn't the issue. I have also tried escaping the comma and not escaping the comma.